# How can I make Light Table automatically close curly braces and square brackets?

Tags: clojure, lighttable

If I type `(` I get `()` but that doesn't work for `{` or `[`. Any Idea why?

What should I do to make it work?

BTW, I am using a French Canadian keyboard (Mac OSX).

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a bug in LT to me, but you can always post your question to its mailing list [Light Table Discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/light-table-discussion), there are a lot of helpful people there.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put something like this on your keymap:

```
{:+ {:editor {"alt-[" [(:editor.open-pair "[")]
              "alt-shift-[" [(:editor.open-pair "{")]
              "alt-]" [(:editor.close-pair "]")]
              "alt-shift-]" [(:editor.close-pair "}")]}}}
```

Reference:
https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/620#issuecomment-30319095

Comment: Doing this actually make `[]` work but when I type `{` i get also `[]`. :S  I'm on a Mac.

Comment: I actually only use us keyboards, but I helped for a while triaging issues on the Lighttable project. But if the comments of that issue don't help, I'm clueless.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is already implemented in the new version of LT:

```
:editor.keys.normal {"\"" [(:editor.repeat-pair "\"")]
                    "(" [(:editor.open-pair "(")]
                    ")" [(:editor.close-pair ")")]                          
                    "[" [(:editor.open-pair "[")]
                    "{" [(:editor.open-pair "{")]
                    "]" [(:editor.close-pair "]")]
                    "}" [(:editor.close-pair "}")]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for Croatian keyboard layout (add it to `user.keymap` file):

```
{:+ {:app {}    
     :editor {"ctrl-alt-f" [(:editor.open-pair "[")]
              "ctrl-alt-b" [(:editor.open-pair "{")]
              "ctrl-alt-g" [(:editor.close-pair "]")]
              "ctrl-alt-n" [(:editor.close-pair "}")]}}}
```